# What is the difference in using attributes() and as.numeric()/as.factor() etc in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out the difference between the two types of structures that we get after cast-typing. The initial output of str() is the one shared first and the second is the one after cast-typing using attributes. Is there a difference between the two? I can't seem to find a difference in the way it behaves, just in the str() output. Why is the output of str() difference when we use attributes() and say as.numeric()?

```
 data_test <- iris
 str(data_test)

#'data.frame':  150 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
# $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
# $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
# $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
# $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 #1 1 1 ...
 cols <- names(data_test)
 classes_cols <- c("numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","factor")

 for (i in (1:length(cols))){
   attributes(obj = data_test[,(cols[i])])$class <- classes_cols[i]
 }

 str(data_test)

#'data.frame':  150 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ Sepal.Length:Class 'numeric'  num [1:150] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
# $ Sepal.Width :Class 'numeric'  num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
# $ Petal.Length:Class 'numeric'  num [1:150] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
# $ Petal.Width :Class 'numeric'  num [1:150] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
# $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34319/r-regression-output-factors-vs-numeric-variables?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference here is that one has an attribute, and the other doesn't. The attribute, "class", is treated a bit specially by `str` as it might refer to an S3 class object.

```
> x=runif(10)
> str(x)
 num [1:10] 0.9621 0.4369 0.0911 0.2425 0.6501 ...
> attr(x,"class")="foo"
> str(x)
Class 'foo'  num [1:10] 0.9621 0.4369 0.0911 0.2425 0.6501 ...
```

Most of the time R doesn't care about attributes on vectors like this, but its the way things like the date and time classes get printed neatly in data frames.

Vectors don't need a class attribute to have a class:

```
> x = runif(10)
> class(x)
[1] "numeric"
> attr(x,"class")
NULL
```

So the difference in printing here is solely down to a vector having a class attribute when it doesn't need one.

Comment: So I am guessing there is no difference in performing operations as I was doing without using attributes()?

Comment: Can I use the attributes function to change class of a vector?

Comment: You weren't really doing anything. And although you *can* use attributes to change class, you probably *shouldn't*. You should either assign to the class (`class(x)<-"foo"`) or use a supplied function (`x <- foo(x)`) or `as.foo` function. Why do you think you need to mess with the attributes?

Comment: I need to do cast typing of many variables at once. I will be reading in a file which will have data types for all my variables, and I need to cast type them accordingly. This seemed to be the best method. Unless you can suggest something. I went to other threads here and have a good idea of how to do it. But, this seemed like short and elegant.

Comment: Well if you want the best answer to that you should probably ask that question. The chances are that there's an option in `read.csv` or one of the `readr` package functions that will read things in with the right type at the start. Ask a new question?